# Type incompatibility error using generics

Tags: java

I have this linked list class implementation `LinkedList` which contains a method `getMode`

```
public class LinkedList<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
{

    //Some code...

    public AnyType mode(){

        //Some code...

            ListNode node;
            AnyType mode;

            mode = node.element;
            return mode;
    }
}
```

The generic variable AnyType is type bound in this linked list class. The same variable is bound in another class `ListNode`. ListNode is not declared in LinkedList. It is an independent class.

```
class ListNode<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
{

    //Some code...

    public AnyType   element;
}
```

I'm wondering why the line in the linked list class

```
mode = node.element;
```

Is giving me a type incompatability error

```
>Required AnyType
Found java.lang.Comparable < >
```

The type bounds for the generic `AnyType` variable is the same in both the node class and the linked list class, so I dont' see why there should be type incompatability here.

The type bound is always

```
 <AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
```

**edit**

Someone has mentioned a solution which appears to work. I had to specify `AnyType` as a bound for the node node variable in the `getMode` method, otherwise the raw type was used or something like that

```
public class LinkedList<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
    {

        //Some code...

        public AnyType mode(){

            //Some code...

                ListNode<AnyType> node; // <--- here
                AnyType mode;

                mode = node.element;
                return mode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is `current` defined?  This is generally an indication that you have a raw type somewhere.

Comment: How do you declare `mode` and `node`?

Comment: Is `Node` declared inside `LinkedList`? If so, it's already generic so you do not need to write `<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>` again.

Comment: @PaulBoddington No, it is an independent class. It's not local in any way.

Comment: @the_prole Ok. In that case I suspect Louis Wasserman is right. We need to see a complete example.

Comment: Okay, someone has found a solution. Thanks peeps.

Answer (score 2):

Because the compiler doesn't know that `AnyType` from your `LinkedList` is the same as the `AnyType` in your `ListNode`

For example, `LinkedList<String>` and `ListNode<Integer>` are both valid (satisfy the bounds upon `AnyType`), but you would probably run into a bunch of issues if a `LinkedList<String>` was handling `ListNode<Integer>`s.

You need to make sure that any `ListNode`s inside of your `LinkedList` class are all declared as `ListNode<AnyType>`.

Side note, the common Java convention would be to use `E` instead of `AnyType` as the name of the generic element type in a collection.